# Installing Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi error

Tags: tensorflow, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

While trying to install Tensorflow on my Raspberry Pi 3B as part of the g2p-seq2seq program I've run into a bit of an issue.

Using the guide [here](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md), I run into an error when executing the command:

```
bazel build -c opt --copt="-mfpu=neon" --local_resources 1024,1.0,1.0 --verbose_failures tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Sandboxed execution is not supported on your system and thus hermeticity of actions cannot be guaranteed. See http://bazel.io/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#sandboxing for more information. You can turn off this warning via --ignore_unsupported_sandboxing.
ERROR: /home/pi/makevoicedemo/tf/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:571:26: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/pi/makevoicedemo/tf/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl", line 565
                rule(attrs = {"srcs": attr.label_list..."), <3 more arguments>)}, <2 more arguments>)
        File "/home/pi/makevoicedemo/tf/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl", line 571, in rule
                attr.label_list(cfg = "data", allow_files = True)
expected ConfigurationTransition or NoneType for 'cfg' while calling label_list but got string instead: data.
ERROR: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package '': Extension file 'tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl' has errors.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.337s
```

I know the Warning notice is not that big of an issue, however I don't know how to fix the two Errors following that. The documentation I found for Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi regarding this issue is difficult to follow. If anyone has any advice I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you're hitting problems! The errors looks like a bug, so could you file this over at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues?

Comment: Ah, I was afraid of that. Thank you, I'll submit the bug report.